# Button only works once

Tags: jquery, button, menu, click, fadein

1. you .click the Menu Button to .fadeIn the `<img>` Menu List which has a `<map>`
2. which in turn .fadeIn a Slideshow and a Back-to-menu Button and .fadeOut the `<img>` Menu List
3. then the Back-to-menu Button .hides the Slideshow

PROBLEM: We should be back at 1. but the menu Button now doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slide").hide(); /* the < imgs > in the slideshow */
    $(".menuList").hide(); /*Menu List is an < img >*/
    $(".backToMenu").hide();
1)  $(".menuButton").on("click", function(){
        $(".menuList").fadeIn(1000);    
    });
2)  $("#photoshop").on("click",function(){ /*one of the menu list < map > < areas >*/
        $(function(){ /* slideshow */
            $(".slideshowPhotoshop img:gt(0)").hide();
            setInterval(function(){
            $(".slideshowPhotoshop :first-child").fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo(".slideshowPhotoshop");},
            4000);
        });
    });
    $(".backToMenu").on("click",function(){
        $(".slideshowPhotoshop").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with an example

Comment: What does a fiddle do exactly?

Comment: I can't find how to use a fiddle. the first link says to download something, but second link doesn't show a download button unless I am missing that. http://stackapps.com/questions/2114/stack-fiddle-easily-create-a-jsfiddle-from-stack-overflow  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-fiddle/loemajeogfdlphofpdfncpbbeoenmbpm

Comment: ***ANSWER***   I used .animated({width:0}); with several other effects and didn't reset the width of the menu list.

Comment: On http://jsfiddle.net/ you can create an example of your piece of code, so we can see the same error that you are having and play 'live' to find a solution.